# My next.js app is not working when deployed

Tags: javascript, css, next.js, deployment

I developed a next.js app with:

```
-npm 9.5.0
-material UI
-react 18.2.0
-next ^13.2.4
```

It works just fine when I run it locally with `npm run dev`, but when I run `npm run start` (after running `npm run build`) the css is gone. I also tried deploying it on Vercel, and in this case not only the css stops working but the API calls as well. I'll leave my git hub repository if anyone wants to take a look at the code:
https://github.com/fdominguezm/ContainerVesselSearchWebApp.git

Let me know if there is any more info I should be telling you guys, and please help me I've been working on this bug for the last week :(.